# how to check first checkbox if any other else is checked, uncheck first checkbox if all other is unchecked

Tags: jquery

I want that if any checkbox is checked, first checkbox should also checked. If all other checkbox is unchecked then first checkbox shouldn't checked @evgeni fotia

```
<form>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"  value="1" name="state">State
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="district">District
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="Police_station">Police Station
</label>
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Should the first one be readonly then? Otherwise if I check `2` then `1` will be checked but I could then uncheck `1`... Not sure the right behaviour here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the below should do it.

The idea is listen for clicks on the "other" checkboxes, and set the checked state of the first one based on if any of the others is checked.

```js
var $firstCb = $("input:checkbox:first");
var $otherCb = $("input:checkbox:not(:first)");

$otherCb.on("click",function(){
   var anyChecked = $otherCb.is(":checked");
   $firstCb.prop("checked",anyChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"  value="1" name="state">State
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="district">District
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="Police_station">Police Station
</label>
```